All subgroups of a group of integers coprime with 7
I am to list all the subgroups of $(\mathbb{Z_7^*}, \cdot)$.
Recall that $\mathbb{Z_7^*}$ is a set of numbers s.t. $\gcd(a, 7) = 1$
I've listed all of them:
$H_1 = \{ 1 \}, \\ H_2 = \{ 1, 2, 4 \}, \\ H_3 = \{ 1, 6 \}, \\ H_4 = \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 \}$
Why is $H = \{ 1, 3, 5 \}$ not a subgroup? Does it have to do with $(\mathbb{Z_7^*}, \cdot)$ is a cyclic group, thus, all the subgroups are also cyclic?

${1,3,5}$ isn't a subgroup because $3^2 = 2$.

This group, also denoted by $U(7)$ is isomorphic to $C_6$. Hence there is exactly one subgroup of order $d$ for each divisor $d$ of $6$.

It is true that all subgroups of $\mathbb Z_7^\times$ are cyclic, but $\{1,3,5\}$ is not a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_7^\times$ because it is not closed under multiplication; e.g., $3\times3=9\equiv\color{blue}2\bmod7$.
